# Nvidia: GPU monitor application

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, gpgpu

What software can show statistics about the usage of the GPU in a graphic interface on Linux. I know that there an [Nvidia System Management](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) which provided the command nvidia-smi -l 1 which shows information in the command line about GPU fan temperature, memory usage and GPU utilization, but I want something more graphic. There is also a [script](http://www.matrix44.net/blog/?p=876) very similar to nvidia-smi that shows percentage of gpu usage and memory usage. I use fedora 16 and the graphic card is a Tesla C1060. To summarize, is there a graphic GPU monitor for linux?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, try lm-sensors.

[Google search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=fedora%20lm_sensors%20gui&oq=fedora%20lm-sensors&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.2604j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: lm-sensors could be used to monitor GPU usage and performance?

Comment: I think lm-sensors is useful only for CPU.